# Does the MouseLeftButtonDown work on WP7 devices?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've recently started work on an application for Windows Phone 7 devices and I haven't yet acquired a WP7 device so I do all the debugging and testing in the emulator.

So. In my application I use the MouseLeftButtonDown event handler to catch a click and navigate from one page to the other. It works perfectly on the emulator but I would like to know for sure if it will work on the real devices as well.

The reason I got doubts is because of the name of the event MouseLeftButtonDown... a phone doesn't have mouse.

So anyone knows? Anyone can try this and tell me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango) all FrameworkElements now support [Tap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.tap%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [DoubleTap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.doubletap%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), and you're recommended to use those instead of the Mouse Events.

Answer (score 1):

If it works in the emulator then it works on the device.  It would be a poor *emulator* that behaved differently from the device in such a fundemental area.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, MouseLeftButtonDown works on the device.